# Why the following code is executed in this order?

Tags: javascript

when i run the following code (by clicking the button):

```js
const div = document.querySelector( "div" )
const button = document.querySelector( "button" )
button.addEventListener( "click", () => {
    console.log( 'clicked' );
    div.textContent = 'printing....';
    var delay = 3000 + new Date().getTime();
    while ( new Date().getTime() < delay ) { }
    console.log( 'after delay' );
} );
```

```html
<button>Run</button>
<div></div>
```

div's content appears after the callback has finished,
so i got upon clicking the first log ( 'clicked') and then after the 3s delay loop the second log ( 'after delay' ) and the text inside the div.
Why 
div.textContent = 'printing....';
isn't executed after the first console.log() ?
Thanks a lot (i'm new in coding and in stackoverflow , so please forgive me if i'm unclear or silly)

Comment: Because the renderer relies on the event loop... which you are preventing from running by having a while loop.

Comment: A "delay" loop like that is an absolutely terrible idea.

Comment: I think you should use `setTimeout`..

Comment: even without the while loop, the text would still render *after* the other console.log, the while loop just makes it noticeable.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is single threaded (for the most part). You're locking up the thread with a busy loop, so the browser will not get a chance to update the page with your changes until your function finishes.

Instead, you'll want to make some changes, then set a timeout, then return, allowing the browser to paint. Later, when the timeout goes off, you can make some more changes.

```
button.addEventListener( "click", () => {
  console.log( 'clicked' );
  div.textContent = 'printing....';
  setTimeout(() = > {
    console.log('after delay');
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: To add up to this - Manipulations like `.textContent = ` related to DOM are part of Web API which is not part of immediately executable code in the current execution context. So, we have to wait for the event loop to do its turn thingy.